# Spring Boot Upload file via PUT

Tags: spring-boot, curl, resttemplate

I have a curl query:

```
curl -v -X PUT --upload-file "test.txt" http://remote_api_service/api/files
```

I have a Spring Boot application and my goal is to write a query that reflects the curl I posted above. How can I do that with RestTemplate or WebClient?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `HttpEntity` with header and body. Set the `content-type` header value to `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file", new FileSystemResource("test.txt"));
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
String serverUrl = "http://remote_api_service/api/files";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.put(serverUrl, requestEntity);
```